# Which one is correct. I oppose to taking a drug or I'm opposed to taking a drug?

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitive-vs-gerund, transitivity

Which is the correct sentence?

1)I oppose to taking a drug.

2)I'm opposed to taking a drug.

I have a problem in understanding the 2nd one.

"I'm opposed" makes sense when there is another subject so I can say I'm opposed by someone or something. But in this case, I tell myself that I hate taking a drug.

Comment: You can _oppose something_ or _be opposed to something_. So 1) should be _I oppose taking a drug_. Which seems correct, but sounds (without context) a bit strange - do you hate taking a specific medication, or are you against "mind altering substances" (_drugs_)?

Comment: mind altering :)

Comment: Then I propose you change your sentences to refer to _drugs_. "A drug" would be a single specific one, even if you do not mention which one. "I'm against taking drugs" _could_ mean I don't trust doctors, but it normally means "I am against people taking cocaine, heroine, etc".

Comment: @oerkelens That is very much a situational-usage issue. He could be referring to a preference for nutritional or physical therapy instead of drug-based medical treatment.

Comment: @chrylis That is why I specifically asked which drug(s) the OP meant, and his answer was "mind altering". "Mind altering substances" are in (almost) all cases understood to be drugs as in the examples I gave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**oppose** is a transitive verb taking a direct object.

> I **oppose** {something}.

An adjective can be formed from the past participle of the verb, indicating *state*.

> I **am opposed to** {something}.
>
> I am opposed to inflationary economic policies.

We  have the verb-to-be (am) and so **opposed** is predicated about the subject, "I".

The prepositional phrase **to inflationary economic policies** indicates that to which I *am opposed*.